# Oracle apex report View

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

Can I create a report like the below screenshot?

[image]

This is being a challenge to create cascaded column like some columns will be grouped into specific parent column.

Comment: Neither Standard nor Interactive reports will output data formatted like you've shown with any of the stock report templates, but that's not to say that it can't be done.  You'll need to provide more info as well as sample data before an accurate answer can be formulated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try pivoting the interactive report ([Actions]->[Format]->[Pivot]) with two columns as Pivot columns.
It will group Parent and Child columns like in the example.
The limitation is to show only numeric data though.